# Presto cannot access AWS S3 data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, presto

I'm trying to connect my local Presto to AWS Glue for metadata and S3 for data. I'm able to connect to Glue and do `show tables;` and `desc <table>;`. However, it's giving me this error when I do `select * from <table>;`

```
Query <query id> failed: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidAccessKeyId; Request ID: <id>; S3 Extended Request ID: <id>)
```

My `hive.properties` file looks like this

```
connector.name=hive-hadoop2

hive.metastore=glue
hive.metastore.glue.region=<region>

hive.s3.use-instance-credentials=false
hive.s3.aws-access-key=<access key>
hive.s3.aws-secret-key=<secret key>
```

Comment: "The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records" means the access key that you are using might be deleted or activated in IAM. Can you verify if it is still there and if not try generating new keys and use them

Answer (score 1):

The error says the credentials are not recognized as valid. Since you can connect to Glue, it seems your environment or ~/.aws has some valid credentials. You should be able to utilize those credentials for S3 access as well.

For this, make sure you are using Presto 332 or better and remove `hive.s3.use-instance-credentials`, `hive.s3.aws-access-key`, `hive.s3.aws-secret-key` from your settings.